# Strange error in C OpenMP parallel program

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm studying patterns for parallel programming. I was going through the examples in the book but one example failed to compile. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {

int i;
int num_steps = 1000000;
double x, pi, step, num = 0.0;

step = 1.0/(double) num_steps;

#pragma omp parallel for private(x) reduction(+:sum)
    for(i=0; i < num_steps; i++) {
        x = (i+0.5) * step;
        sum+= 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
    }

pi = step *sum;
printf("pi %lf\n", pi);
return 0;
}
```

[image]

I'm new to PP so I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Unless there's something I'm missing here it just looks like you never create a variable called `sum`.

Comment: Strange example from the book, strange that it presents an error. Is there a possibility to overcome it?

Comment: Create a variable declaration for sum, `double sum = 0.0;`

Comment: there is a mis-print (or keypunch) error.  This line: 'double x, pi, step, num = 0.0;' should be: 'double x, pi, step, sum = 0.0;'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no variable for `sum` declared in the code so when the compiler gets to the line:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(x) reduction(+:sum)
```

It doesn't know what `sum` is and gives you the compilation error you ran into.

To fix this you need to declare the `sum` variable first:

```
double sum = 0.0;
#pragma omp parallel for private(x) reduction(+:sum)
```

As pointed out in the comments the problem is as the result of a typo:

```
double x, pi, step, num = 0.0; //num should be sum here
```

By compiling with all warnings `-Wall` compiler option for gcc you would get a warning  about an unused variable `num` which would fairly quickly point out the source of the problem here.

Comment: you should notice that 'num' is never used.  (compiling with all warnings enabled would show that problem.)  This makes it obvious that the declaration of 'num = 0.0' should be 'sum=0.0'.

Comment: @user3629249, indeed. Great example of why compiling with all warnings enabled is a good idea.

Comment: How do I enable all warnings in ubuntu?

Comment: @Lucas, see the edit to my answer for me information.

Comment: Sorry to be so pedantic but `-Wall` does not enable all warnings. Neither does `-Wall -Wextra`. It's a misnomer for GCC do call it `all`. Maybe it should have been `-Wmost -Wmore` :-)